# equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the sets $X = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and $Y = \{0,2,4,6,8,9\} $
.In $\mathcal P(X)$ I define the equivalence relation such that $A\mathrel RB$ iff $A - Y = B - Y$. How many equivalence classes are there?or, cardinal of the quotient set $ \mathcal{P} (X)/R$?

I know the cardinal value of the set $\mathcal{P} (X)/R$ is $16$ but I do not know how to get to this result.

Comment: What does $A/Y$ mean?

Comment: I read it as $A\setminus Y$ and $B\setminus Y$, where $\mathcal{P}(X)/R$ denotes the collection of equivalence classes. However, I'd expect there to be $32$ of those, currently. @Jose: are you sure $10\in X$?

Comment: @HSN: Yes, $\mathcal P(X)/R$ is the quotient set; I was asking specifically about the $A/Y$ part. As for the numerical answer, $16$ is correct (under the set difference interpretation).

Comment: @AsafKaragila are you sure $16$ is correct?  I would have agreed with HSN on $32$.

Comment: I agree with @David. It's actually $P(\{1,3,5,7,10\}) = 2^5 = 32$.

Comment: I have trouble counting. But This is equivalent to $\mathcal P(X\setminus Y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that $A/Y$ means the set difference, $A$ with elements of $Y$ (if any) removed.  Then $A\,R\,B$ means that $A$ and $B$ contain the same elements which are not in $Y$, that is the same out of the elements $\{1,3,5,7,10\}$.  For example, $\{1,2,4\}$ is related to $\{1,4,6,8\}$.  Can you finish the problem from here?

**Comment**: $A/Y$ is more usually written as $A-Y$ or $A\backslash Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: There is a unique equivalence class for each subset of $\{1,3,5,7\}$ (this is the set of elements in $X$ but not in $Y$.